# How can I open a page in an newly tabbed iframe?

Tags: hyperlink, html, iframe

I am trying to open a link in a new tab.  Easy enough.  But I also want it to be in an iframe so that I can cut off the top of the page.  Is this doable?  For example, is it possible to do something like this broken code?:

```
<a href="//stackexchange.com" target="_blank iframe">StackExchange</a>

iframe {
    margin-top: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not like that, make a page to catch it (if you control the page):

```
<a href="my_iframeCatcher.php?url=//stackexchange.com" target="_blank">StackExchange</a>
```

And the contents of `my_iframeCatcher.php` would be along the lines of:

```
<div>your top banner</div>
<iframe src="<?=urlencode($_GET['url'])?>"></iframe>
```

Alternatively, you can add a base tag to do this for you, this way the prepend and `target` doesnt have to be placed for each anchor, but this makes ALL anchors prepended (which you might not want):

```
<base href="_iframeCatcher.php?url=" target="_blank">
```

---

If you do not control the page, things get a lot more difficult fast. This would require you to get the contents of the page, and then find a method to prepend the `my_iframeCatcher.php?url=` to each url.

You want do a PHP `file_get_contents()`, of find a clever way to use javascript. I recommend to try the javascript first, if you do the `file_get_contents()` method, you will use up your bandwidth downloading all those pages.